# Carrierwave and Heroku error ("undefined method `image_wil l_change!")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Everything works fine locally but after deploying to Heroku, I can't upload any photos. 
Here's the heroku logs. I already ran heroku rake db:migrate and I've already set the cached directory as per the carrierwave wiki but I'm not sure how to resolve this one.

```
2013-03-15T08:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/posts" for xx.xx.xx.xx
 at 2013-03-15 08:11:39 +0000
2013-03-15T08:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-15T08:11:39+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/posts h
ost=boiling-bastion-xxxx.herokuapp.com fwd="xx.xx.xx.xx" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait
=0ms connect=2ms service=1847ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-15T08:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-15T08:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `image_wil
l_change!' for #<Post:0x00000005ab1698>):
2013-03-15T08:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-15T08:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
:6:in `create'
2013-03-15T08:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-15T08:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11m
s
2013-03-15T08:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#create
as HTML
2013-03-15T08:11:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"???", "authenticit
y_token"=>"rR7KrBprIx=", "post"=>{"content
"=>"test", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005ac28a8 @origi
nal_filename="423366.jpg", @content_type="image/jp
eg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filena
me=\"423366.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
, @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130315-2-1mskj82>>}, "commit"=>"Post"}
```

ImageUploader Class

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
storage :file
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end
def filename
     "#{secure_token(10)}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
   end

   def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end
```

My schema.db

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.string   "image"
    t.text     "commentcontent"
    t.text     "comment_content"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the column `image` in your `Post`.

I believe you have something like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

So, you need to create a migration to add the `image` column:

```
rails g migration AddImageToPosts image:string
```

Finally,

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: looking at my schema.db, there is a image column under Posts. I updated the original post with the schema. Does it mean maybe heroku doesn't have it though? I did run heroku rake db:migrate already right after deployment

Comment: ok, lets check your `schema.rb` at heroku: `heroku run bash -a yourappname`, `cd db`, `cat schema.rb`. can you see the column?